# How to change isEnabled and alpha properties of UIButton base on validation using RXSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

This is what I simply try to achieve using:

```
let observable = Observable.combineLatest(loginProperty.asObservable(), passwordProperty.asObservable()) { _,_ in
    self.viewModel.isValid
}
observable.bind(to: mainView.loginButton.rx.isEnabled).disposed(by: disposeBag)
//observable.bind(to: mainView.loginButton.rx.alpha).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

But this can be bound only to `isEnabled` property. I would like to also change alpha of my `loginButton`. How can I do that?

Comment: Why not RxAction or CocoaAction

Comment: How to use it with RxAction or CocoaAction? Would you post an answer? Thank you;)

Comment: lemme add one please wait

Comment: Take a look n tell me if it helps :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to write Reactive extension to bind the property.

```
extension Reactive where Base : UIButton {
    public var valid : Binder<Bool> {
        return Binder(self.base) { button, valid in
            button.isEnabled = valid
            button.alpha = 0.5 // You Value as per valid or not
        }
    }
}
```

Then write like this to check the Observable value

```
observable.bind(to: mainView.loginButton.rx.valid).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I simply test that method in unit testing?